# Command line pdf joiner

Tags: pdf, software-rec

Is there a command line pdf joiner somewhere out there ?
I need to join about 300 pdf files (well, 368 to be exact, not including toc and frontpage) and I can't see any way to do it simply using foxit editor.

Since I've had to do this a few times now, I'd like something simple and preferably scriptable so the whole process can be automated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what OS you're running, [The PDF Toolkit](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) should work.

Straight from their docs:

```
pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf cat output 123.pdf
```

Comment: Given the number of files, a wildcard would be more useful.
pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf

Comment: Hopefully he gets the idea.  I just copy/pasted it from the toolkit's website.  =-]

Comment: I'm just downloading it, and if it works like they say, then it will be the exact thing I was hoping to find. Thanks (I was looking for Windows solution, btw) !!

Comment: @dentrasi - I created the filenames, so I can easily recreate the list in the right order. Besides, how would you use a wildcard without knowing the order in which they need to be joined ?

Answer (score 1):

[PDF Split and Merge](http://www.pdfsam.org/) is a tool I've had great success with, and it comes in GUI and command-line flavours. If the command-line version is anything like the GUI, you should have no problem scripting a solution.